# Cover has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Tags: ruby-on-rails

En Ruby 2.3.3 On Rails 5.1.7
Al instalar paperclip me aparecía error con cover al subir las imágenes así que instalé GnuWin y funciona correctamente pero cuando levanté el sistema en el servidor, en los equipos aparece el mismo error.
Hay una forma de no instalar a todos los usuarios el GnuWin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay gemas (no todas) que, para poder compilar, requieren librerías sólo disponibles en sistemas *nix (Linux,Osx, etc). Por lo tanto, mientras estés usando Windows, debes disponer de dichas librerías a través de programas como `Cygwin` o `GnuWin32` para poder usar dichas gemas.
Ahora, si con instalar a todos los usuarios `GnuWin`,te refieres a que cada usuario que ingrese a tu página debe tenerlo instalado, no, eso no debería ser necesario.
Si estás recibiendo ese tipo de error al acceder desde otros computadores y no del tuyo, probablemente tenga que ver [con un `content-type` erróneo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1924#issuecomment-139326429) que puede estar mandando el explorador a tu servidor.
De todas formas, esto es solo una conjetura y creo que deberías complementar tu pregunta con más detalles o crear una nueva pregunta donde des más detalles de cómo tienes configurado paperclip, cual es el content-type que recibes desde donde no te da problemas y desde donde si lo hace, que explorador(es) está(s) usando, etc.

Comment: Gracias tienes razón, cuando pasé el sistema a Linux ya no había problemas.